Blocking [IPaddress:8080] on nginx
I have an app working on port 8080 perfectly with the domain desh.onecloudhelper.com and now when I hit the Public IP address of the Server, I can still view the same app running using the server's public IP address.
What I am trying to achieve is that If someone uses the [IPaddress:8080] to access the site, that request should be blocked but when someone accesses the site using the [domainname:8080], that request should not be blocked through the browser.
This is the config file that I am using:
server {
listen 80;
server_name desh.onecloudhelper.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}


The domain would resolve to the IP first, so you'd end up blocking both

If someone uses the [IPaddress:8080] to access the site, that request should be blocked but when someone accesses the site using the [domainname:8080], that request should not be blocked.

I understood that from the post, but DNS would resolve first by the client, then the IP is used to connect. Nginx doesn't know about the domain name other than the Host header in the request body

fyi this is a question for [unix.se], [ubuntu.se], or [su], not Stack Overflow (it's not a programming question)
